# lodash method to merge 2 objects of different sizes

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any method to merge 2 arrays of objects like this

```
var a = [{id: 1, val: 1},{id: 2, val: 2},{id: 3, val: 3},{id: 4, val: 4},{id: 5, val: 5}];
var b = [{id: 21, val: 21},{id: 22, val: 22},{id: 23, val: 23}]

//final result should be
c = [
  {id:1, val: 1},
  {id:21, val: 21},
  {id:2, val: 2},
  {id:22, val: 22},
  {id:3, val: 3},
  {id:23, val: 23},
  {id:4, val: 4},
  {id:5, val: 5}
]
```

offcourse I can create it by myself, but just want to check whether lodash provide it or not

Comment: Like card shuffling? One from this array and one from the other ...?

Comment: Yes correct......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = [{id: 1, val: 1},{id: 2, val: 2},{id: 3, val: 3},{id: 4, val: 4},{id: 5, val: 5}];
var b = [{id: 21, val: 21},{id: 22, val: 22},{id: 23, val: 23}];

// loop through the biggest array and reduce the result (no need for the value we just need the accumulator and the index)
var result = _.reduce(a.length < b.length? b: a, function(res, _, i) {
  if(i < a.length) res.push(a[i]); // if there is still elements in a, push the current one
  if(i < b.length) res.push(b[i]); // if there is still elements in b, push the current one
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the more optimized approach would be to move `length` determining out of loop. **Hint**: See my approach `aLen = a.length, bLen = b.length`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I wanted this to be a one expression solution, otherwise I would've used `_.forEach` and push to an outer variable `result` and do all the tests outside!

Answer (score 2):

You could first [**zip**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zip) the arrays, [**flatten**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatten) the result and then use [**compact**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#compact) to remove the missing array elements (zip adds them as undefined):

```
var c = _.compact(_.flatten(_.zip(a,b)))
```

Or using chaining:

```
var c = _(a)
    .zip(b)
    .flatten()
    .compact()
    .value()
```

```js
var a = [{id: 1, val: 1},{id: 2, val: 2},{id: 3, val: 3},{id: 4, val: 4},{id: 5, val: 5}];
var b = [{id: 21, val: 21},{id: 22, val: 22},{id: 23, val: 23}]

var c = _(a)
    .zip(b)
    .flatten()
    .compact()
    .value()
    
document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Ecmascript5* solution using `Math.max()`(to find the larger array size) and `Array.prototype.push()` functions:

```js
var a = [{id: 1, val: 1},{id: 2, val: 2},{id: 3, val: 3},{id: 4, val: 4},{id: 5, val: 5}],
    b = [{id: 21, val: 21},{id: 22, val: 22},{id: 23, val: 23}],
    maxLen = Math.max(a.length, b.length), aLen = a.length, bLen = b.length,
    maxList = aLen > bLen ? a : b;
    result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    (i < aLen && i < bLen) ? result.push(a[i], b[i]) : result.push(maxList[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could use a function which iterates to the minimum length of both, assembles the values and concat the rest at the end.

```js
function insert(a, b) {
    var c = [],
        i = 0,
        l = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    while (i < l) {
        c.push(a[i], b[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return c.concat(a.slice(i), b.slice(i));
}

var a = [{ id: 1, val: 1 }, { id: 2, val: 2 }, { id: 3, val: 3 }, { id: 4, val: 4 }, { id: 5, val: 5 }],
    b = [{ id: 21, val: 21 }, { id: 22, val: 22 }, { id: 23, val: 23 }];

console.log(insert(a, b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```